# 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

On the 'panel' page, I have a choice field with a list of uploaded documents or 'bots' as I usually refer to them. This list only displays 'bots' that have been uploaded by the current user.

```
panel\forms.py

from django import forms
import os

from upload.models import Document

#### RETRIEVE LIST OF BOTS UPLOADED BY CURRENT USER ####
def get_files(user):
    bots = Document.objects.filter(user=user.id)
    file_list = []
    for b in bots:
        file_list.append((b.id,b.docfile))
    return file_list

class botForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(botForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bot'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_files(user))
```

This works fine and displays a list of all the users bots. The problem arises when I try to pass these values over to the 'game' page and access them here.

```
game\views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from game.models import game
from game.forms import GameForm
from upload.models import Document
from panel.forms import botForm
import league

def RPS(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the request is a POST method...

        if 'PanelPlay' in request.POST:
            panel = botForm(request.POST)
            if panel.is_valid():
                print panel.cleaned_data['bot']

        elif 'GamePlay' in request.POST:
            form = GameForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
            if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                leagueOuput = []
                leagueOutput = league.run(form.cleaned_data['bot1'],form.cleaned_data['bot2'])
                newGame = game()
                newGame.bot1 = leagueOutput[0]
                newGame.bot2 = leagueOutput[1]
                newGame.bot1wins = leagueOutput[2]
                newGame.bot2wins = leagueOutput[3]
                newGame.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('game.views.RPS')) # Redirect after POST

    form = GameForm() # An unbound form
    results = game.objects.all()    # Load messages for the list page     

    return render_to_response('game.html', {'results': results, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When attempting to access and validate the panel data, I get the following error.

> 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'id'

Referring to this specific line.

```
bots = Document.objects.filter(user=user.id)
```

I have found and read about a number of similar issues but I can't seem to carry over their solutions to my own project.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Please give the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are constructing the `botForm`, you're passing `request.POST` (a QueryDict) as the `user` parameter. Did you mean

```
panel = botForm(request.user, data=request.POST)
```

?

(assuming you're using django authentification).

Comment: You solved my problem, you beautiful person. If you couldn't tell I'm not very experienced and basically piecing things together from sources as I go.